# How to uninstall Qt5?

Tags: qt, qt4, ubuntu-14.04, qt5

Somehow I ended up with 2 versions of Qt on my `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` machine, Qt4 and Qt5. Here is the output of `qtchooser -list-versions`

```
4
5
config
default
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

How do I remove Qt5?

Answer (score 21):

1. Open a terminal and navigate to the directory where Qt is installed.
2. Run the command `./MaintenanceTool`.

Answer (score 13):

#### From The Terminal:

###### 1. Remove the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove qtcreator && sudo apt-get remove qt5*
```

###### 2. Remove all the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get purge qtcreator && sudo apt-get purge qt5*
```

##### 3. Remove the unneeded packages that were once installed as a dependency:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

###### 4. Remove the retrieved packages from the local cache:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

---

#### From the GUI:

1. Open Qt Maintenance Tool [image: Qt Maintenance Tool]
2. Tick **Uninstall** [image: Uninstall]
3. Click **next**, then **Uninstall** [image]
4. Enter the Sudo password if requested then, press **Finish**.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove/uninstall Qt Creator then follow this:

Open your terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T), then...

1. To only uninstall Qt Creator:

   `sudo apt-get remove qtcreator`
2. If you want to remove Qt Creator and its dependent packages as well:

   `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove qtcreator`

Reference website:
https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/qtcreator?type=uninstall

Answer (score 7):

Just remove the Qt5 dev packages, that should do it:

```
sudo apt autoremove '.*qt5.*-dev'
```

Inspect the shown list of packages to be removed **carefully** before hitting *yes*, though! If there are some you want to keep, do `apt install` for them to mark them manually installed.

Comment: I would like to remove all Qt form my ubuntu-16.04, how can I achieve that?

Comment: After doing this I still see Qt 4 and 5 both in ```qtchooser -list-versions```

Comment: @UrviG As a guess, you still have both qmake's. Perhaps you have marked them manually installed at some point, so they didn't get removed. Inspect list of installed packages.

Comment: Thanks @hyde 
This is the output for that command.

```4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5```

I only intend to completely wipe off QT, on this system(ubuntu 16.04) previously different versions of QT are installed and start all over again..Can I proceed despite this output?

Answer (score 3):

1. Where is your qtchooser configuration file?

   `$: locate qtchooser | grep conf`
2. From the list of conf files, probably there is one call "default.conf". This one is a link to one of the others (4.conf or qt4.conf or 5.conf or qt5.conf). Choose the one that makes sense to you, and create a link to it.

   Suppose your default file path is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf`.

   Create a backup:

   ```
   $: cd $(dirname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf)
   $: cp -av default.conf default.conf_backup
   ```

   Let's say your target is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf`, then:

   ```
   $: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf default.conf
   ```
3. Is the path to your qmake right?

   Check the qmake location:

   ```
   $: locate qmake | grep bin
   ```

   Is this the same one as indicated in your modified qtchooser/default.conf?

   ```
   $: cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf
   ```

   If the answer is yes, then you are done.
   If the answer is no, then you need to modify the file:

   Create a backup:

   ```
   $: cd $(dirname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf)
   $: cp -av qt5.conf qt5.conf_backup
   ```

   Edit the file and change the path to your qmake location:

   ```
   $ sudo vi qt5.conf
   ```

   Now it is done.